# phonegap ajax request error over ssl

Tags: ajax, ssl, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to post request over SSL in my Phonegap application dedicated especially for Windows Phone platform. Everything works on our development server, but when I switched to production, my AJAX request failed. Below I paste my AJAX call. I've tested my application on Android, iOS and Windows Phone device. It doesn't work only on Windows Phone. Any helper logs from xhr object are empty... I can't figure out what's wrong. Is this problem might be releated because of certificate we use on our production server? Or there are any restrictions that prevent call AJAX request over SSL in Windows Phone? I even don't know how to start debug because all logs are empty... Your help would be greatly appreciated!

**Here is my code**

```
$.ajax({
    url: myServiceUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: myXmlData,
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        onSuccess(data, status, xhr);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(thrownError);
        onError(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
    }
});
```

**My Logs**

```
Log:["error","DebugConsole517333971"]
The thread 0xe4c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
Log:["error","DebugConsole517333972"]
The thread 0xed4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
Log:["","DebugConsole517333973"]
The thread 0x360 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
Log:["","DebugConsole517333974"]
```

Comment: add "phonegap" tag, I'm trying but Edit doesnt work well ;)

Comment: I've tried, but it's renamed to "cordova" tag :)

Comment: Aah, it's not good. It's not the same :)

Comment: **UPDATE (solved):** After long days of debugging I've found soulution... It was cross-domain request of course and if you want to execute POST request over SSL your `dataType` must be **jsonp**. It's written in documentation https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ under **crossDomain** setting. My communication was based on SOAP protocol (xml data) that prevent to execute any request. If I post request on server **without** SSL protection (still SOAP), it also works. Probably jQuery treated my request as unsafe. I hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long days of debugging I've found soulution... It was cross-domain request of course and if you want to execute POST request over SSL your `dataType` must be `jsonp`. It's written in documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax under `crossDomain` setting. My communication was based on SOAP protocol (xml data) that prevent to execute any request. If I post request on server without SSL protection (still SOAP), it also works. Probably jQuery treated my request as unsafe. I hope this might help someone.